# execute php script with exec() in php-fpm pool

Tags: php, exec, command-line-interface, apc

Webserver is configured as php-fpm pool per site configuration.

I am tryin to get my php "kind-a" asynchronous by using php

`exec('bash -c "exec php index.php" > /dev/null 2>&1 &')`

I am using successfully php apc cache but the cache of php-pool is obviously not shared with cache of above executed cli command. Is there any possibility to execute a php script with exec() IN the php-fpm pool from which the script is called by exec()?
An option like

```
exec('php-fpm --pool=domain.tld index.php')
```

I could not find any information about how apache calls a php pool process in a php-fpm pool configuration to get an idea of how it's done.

Comment: Is there any valid reason to execute the script via CLI? I think if you only need to do asynchronous tasks you can use pthreads PECL extension for Multi-threading, it needs PHP to be compiled Thread Safe: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php

Comment: I believe this is not executed async, because the process which calls exec will wait for the result. You should use PHP Threads as @GrowingBrick said. Alternatively you can use a trigger file, which for example makes a cronjob runable. But apc is only visible to one process and you can't join the process from an other process. When you would like to have a shared Cache, you should use something different like Redis.